# Do Gild's Gold tokens go into play under the caster's control?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Gild](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378445) says "Exile target creature. Put a colorless artifact token named Gold onto the battlefield. It has "Sacrifice this artifact: Add one mana of any color to your mana pool."". I assume that that means that the token goes into play under your control (assuming you were the one who cast Gild) and not the person who's creature you exiled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the token comes into play under the control of the player who played Gild. This is specified by rule [110.2a](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Permanent):

> If an effect instructs a player to put an object onto the battlefield, that object enters the battlefield under that player's control unless the effect states otherwise.

Gild's effect instructs *you* (the player who controls the spell) to put the token into play, so it comes into play under your control.

A ruling on the Gatherer page states this explicitly:

> You will control the token, no matter who controls the target creature.

Comment: [Rapid Hybridization](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366388) is a good example where the token goes to the other player, showing how it's explicitly stated. "Destroy target creature. It can't be regenerated. That creature's controller puts a 3/3 green Frog Lizard creature token onto the battlefield."

Comment: It's also an explicit Oracle ruling: _You will control the token, no matter who controls the target creature._

Comment: Yes, it is, but the rules are sufficient to know what happens.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The big reason to mention the rulings is that a lot of people don't think to look there, and it'll help them get quick answers in the future, rather than having to post a question here or try to search/understand the comp rules.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite.

It enters the battlefield under the control of Gild's controller.

> 110.2a. If an effect instructs a player to put an object onto the battlefield, that object enters the battlefield under that player's control unless the effect states otherwise.

That's Gild's controller when it resolved.

By default, that's the player who cast Gild.

By default, that's the player who owns Gild.

So by default, it'll come under control of the player who owns Gild, but as you can see, there are some variables.

Comment: A couple of technicalities: there are no triggered abilities in this scenario. Gild doesn't enter the battlefield because it's a sorcery. And I'm pretty sure that there's no way to change the controller of an effect of a spell once the spell starts resolving. Really, the only variable here is the controller of the spell when it resolves.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Yeah, I seem to have seriously misread the card. Fixed.

Comment: (And while I know you two both know it, of course the controller of the spell _could_ be swapped on the stack by, e.g., Perplexing Chimera; so 'when it resolves' is still necessary text.)